# Triple conditioned do while loop

Tags: javascript, loops

I'm trying to assign three random numbers to three variables (`random1`, `random2`, `random3`), and then assign these random variables to three elements. But I don't want any of them to be equal to the variable `Sum` which is the addition of two numeric `innerHTML` values.

So I have done that using `do...while` loop, but unfortunately the `do...while` loop doesn't work as expected .

Here is my code :

```
setTimeout(function () {
    z.innerHTML = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1);

    setTimeout(function applySUM() {
        var Sum = parseInt(document.getElementById('fir').innerHTML) +
            parseInt(document.getElementById('sec').innerHTML);
        ch1.innerHTML = Sum;
    }, 500);

    do {
        var random1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1);
        var random2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (6 - 4 + 1)) + 4;
        var random3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (10 - 7 + 1)) + 7;
    } while (random1 == Sum || random2 == Sum || random3 == Sum);

    setTimeout(function func() {
        ch2.innerHTML = random1;
    }, 1000);

    setTimeout(function func() {
        ch3.innerHTML = random2;
    }, 1500);

    setTimeout(function func() {
        ch4.innerHTML = random3;
    }, 2000);

}, 2000);
```

Looking at the code above, it seems to be impossible for the `ch2.innerHTML`, `ch3.innerHTML` and `ch4.innerHTML` to be equal to `Sum`, but when I test it the reality says something else. Why is this?

Comment: It is a little unclear what actually happens, so for clarification, the inner html of `ch2`, `ch3`, and `ch4` are all getting set to sum, and you do not expect this, correct?

Comment: What's the reason for all the `setTimeout`s? The variables `Sum` is **local** to the `setTimeout` callback and therefore not accessible in the condition of the `do...while` loop. I'm surprised the code runs at all. Please add the variables definitions that are currently not included in this example and create a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo.

Comment: You have a problem of scope. `Sum` is defined within the scope of the function called by the nested setTimeout (not the setTimeout function you are specifying).  It don't really best know how to give advise to fix this as it seems very odd the way you are making all these calls to `setTimeout()`. I am not sure what you are actually trying to do.

Comment: sometimes what i want just happens & neither of the ch2.innerHTML, ch3.innerHTML and ch4.innerHTML are equal to Sum , but sometimes one or more of them are equals to Sum which is the issue that i don't want it to happen , and this issue leads me to the fact that my do while loop is not fully correct

Comment: to fix the problem MikeBrant and FelixKling are talking about, try declaring and setting sum before the setTimeout, then inside the set timeout you can set the innerHTML as you wish.

Answer (score 2):

First thing, as many people mentioned, the sum variable is local to ApplySum so the rest of your code is referencing a global Sum variable instead (and it is "undefined" by default)

Another problem is that right now your do-while loop runs immediately, *without* waiting the 500 ms timeout and before Sum is assigned to a value. You can fix this by putting your code inside the settimeout callbacks:

```
z.innerHTML = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1);

setTimeout(function applySUM() {
    var Sum = parseInt(document.getElementById('fir').innerHTML) +
        parseInt(document.getElementById('sec').innerHTML);
    ch1.innerHTML = Sum;


    do {
        var random1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1);
        var random2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (6 - 4 + 1)) + 4;
        var random3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (10 - 7 + 1)) + 7;
    } while (random1 == Sum || random2 == Sum || random3 == Sum);

    setTimeout(function func() {
        ch2.innerHTML = random1;
    }, 500);

    setTimeout(function func() {
        ch3.innerHTML = random2;
    }, 1000);

    setTimeout(function func() {
       ch4.innerHTML = random3;
    }, 1500);

}, 500);
```

(I also decreased 500ms from the other settimeouts to compensate for them being moved inside the first timeout)

Another tiny change you could consider is doing a separate loop for each variable instead of a single one for all of them.

```
var random1, random2, random3;
do { random1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1);          } while (random1 == Sum);
do { random2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (6 - 4 + 1)) + 4;  } while (random2 == Sum);
do { random3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (10 - 7 + 1)) + 7; } while (random3 == Sum);
```

Answer (score 1):

The comments about scope seem like they're on the right track.  Here's the relevant part of your code:

```
setTimeout(function applySUM() {
    var Sum = parseInt(document.getElementById('fir').innerHTML) +
        parseInt(document.getElementById('sec').innerHTML);
    ch1.innerHTML = Sum;
}, 500);
// Outside of your applySum function, Sum has no meaning

do {
    var random1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1);
    var random2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (6 - 4 + 1)) + 4;
    var random3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (10 - 7 + 1)) + 7;
} while (random1 == Sum || random2 == Sum || random3 == Sum);
// Outside of your loop body, random1, random2, and random3 have no meaning
// undefined == undefined => true
```

Perhaps if you changed it to this:

```
var Sum = 0;
setTimeout(function applySUM() {
    Sum = parseInt(document.getElementById('fir').innerHTML) +
        parseInt(document.getElementById('sec').innerHTML);
    ch1.innerHTML = Sum;
}, 500);

var random1 = random2 = random3 = undefined;
do {
    random1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1);
    random2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (6 - 4 + 1)) + 4;
    random3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (10 - 7 + 1)) + 7;
} while (random1 == Sum || random2 == Sum || random3 == Sum);
```

Then your variables might have scope in the appropriate spots.  Just a hunch, there might be something else wrong with this.

Comment: Beat me to it.  However, you should put the `Sum = parseInt(document.getElementById('fir').innerHTML) +
        parseInt(document.getElementById('sec').innerHTML);` outside the setTimeout as well, it seems clear to me that the user needs those specfic values, and only wants to wait to display to content on the page.

Comment: I suppose that would make sense, although I truly have no idea what he was trying to accomplish with this code.  I was just addressing the programming error, not anything related to strategy or style.  Why don't you submit an answer with a more nuanced understanding of the situation?  I'd upvote a cleaner, clearer rewrite.